# java socket. How to server know client close stream

Tags: java, file, sockets, stream

I want to write a transfer file socket-program in java . 
But i have problem, how to cancel when transferring file.

when i close inputstream in client, how to server know it to close outputstream.

here is my code:
Client

```
                   try {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                    "/mnt/sdcard/UML.doc");
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            int total = 0;
            while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1 && !canceled) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / size));
                fos.write(data, 0, count);

            }

            if(canceled)
            {
                is.close();
                fos.close();
                //socket.close();
                pDialog.dismiss();
                File file = new File("mnt/sdcard/UML.doc");
                file.delete();

                canceled=false;

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
```

......

Server

```
           BufferedInputStream bis = null;

                    bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                            myFile));

                    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    os = s.getOutputStream();
                    int total = 0;

                    try {

                        os.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

                        // os.flush();
                    }
                    catch(SocketException e){
                        os.flush();
                        tv.setText("aaaaa");
                    }
```

......

But nothing display when i close inputstream

Comment: If it makes sense for your project, I think you should check out ZeroMQ: http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:java

Comment: I think you need a loop to read and send until the whole file is processed.

Answer (score 1):

When the client closes the `InputStream` in the middle of a transmission, a `SocketException` will be thrown on the server side.

Comment: Make that *very* eventually.  It can take up to a few minutes depending upon the exact circumstances under which the client socket went away.

Comment: It will throw an `IOException` 'connection reset'. Not a `SocketException`.

Comment: @EJP Just FYI, `SocketException` is a *subclass* of `IOException`.  And in reality, if you try to log the exception being thrown, it will always precisely tell you that it's a `SocketException` instead of its super class.

Comment: @shinkou, 'Just FYI', the exception that is thrown is an `IOException,` not a `SocketException.`

Comment: @EJP: does the exception change for a RST vs a FIN vs ICMP unreachable vs a timeout?

Comment: @sarnold There is no exception for a `FIN`: rather, `read()` returns -1. You can't get ICMP UNREACH on a read.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a try-catch block.
pseudocode:

```
try{
    //your file transferring code here through socket output streams
} catch(SocketException e) {
    /* now as you are in this block you got a socket closed 
      Exception and your server now knows about it */
}
```

Comment: can you see my code above, i do this try-catch block but nothing display.

Comment: i tried, but still not work. can you show me example code? please.

Comment: `SocketClosed` exception is thrown when *you* close the socket and continue to use it. Not when the *peer* closes the *connection.*